# DAX - Get the value of the most recent record of a column

Tags: powerbi, dax

In Power BI Desktop, I want a calculated measure to get the last value of a given day of column `Saldo em EUR`:

[image]

This is the closing balance of a bank account and the relevant one for each day is the one in the first position, because the bank arranges the bank statement like that and since there's no information about the hour each record took place, this is the only way I can get the closing balance for any given day.

This is what I'm trying:

```
Saldo do dia = CALCULATE(SUM('BankStatement'[Saldo em EUR]);FILTER('BankStatement';'BankStatement'[Data Valor]=MAX('BankStatement'[Data Valor])))
```

However this is adding all values of column `Saldo em EUR` for each day. It is returning `10.632,60` instead of `793,80`.

Here's a link for the CSV file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vc6c4rV7-NpE1ClbF0dYcWa0PhH4hIMr38QU4EFKuxc

Comment: Good question, but it would be even more helpful if you include a sample CSV dataset and explicit expected value (as opposed to a screenshot), so we can easily verify any solution we might give.

Comment: If you are sure that the first row contains the last value you can use FIRSTNONBLANK function. Be more specific about your expected result, what is the context against the measure should be calculated?

Comment: Pls. see my edited question above with link to CSV file. Thanks!

Comment: @NunoNogueira, if you can create a row number or incremental index column then you could create a calculated column simulating the SQL partition by [Date Mov.] behaviour using a DAX expression. Then just use that column to get the value

Answer (score 1):

Add INDEX column and for each day pick the value in row with highest/lowest (depending on if index is ascending or descending) INDEX value.